# RecyclerView item swipe update background textview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, swipe, motionevent

I have a problem and I am stuck at this point. I used recyclerview swipe on each item of recyclerview. What I need to do is to update the textview with 1, 2 and so on as the swipe is moving right just like this.
[image: image of recyclerview]

I am getting the x-axis value with event.getRaw(x) and i need to increase the amount as the x value is increasing from left to right and decrease the count if the swipe is moving from right to left. Here is my code.

```
holder.swipeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            int downX, upX, initialX = 0, rightX;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        startX = event.getRawX();
                        startY = event.getRawY();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        float x = event.getRawX();

                        float y = event.getRawY();
                        // Calculate move update. This will happen many times
                        // during the course of a single movement gesture.

                        scrollByX = x - startX; // move update x increment
                        scrollByY = y - startY; // move update y increment

                        startX = x; // reset initial values to latest
                        startY = y;

                        if (scrollByX >= 100 && scrollByX < 150)
                            holder.leftTextView.setText("1");
                        if (scrollByX >= 150 && scrollByX < 200)
                            holder.leftTextView.setText("2");
                        if (scrollByX >= 200 && scrollByX < 250)
                            holder.leftTextView.setText("3");
                        if (scrollByX >= 250 && scrollByX < 300)
                            holder.leftTextView.setText("4");
                        if (scrollByX >= 350 && scrollByX < 400)
                            holder.leftTextView.setText("5");

                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        upX = (int) event.getX();
                        Log.i("event.getX()", " upX " + downX);
                        holder.swipeLayout.animateReset();
                        //holder.leftTextView.setText("0");
                        scrollByX = 0;
                        scrollByY = 0;
                        if (upX - downX > 100) {

                            // swipe right
                        }

                        else if (downX - upX > -100) {

                            // swipe left
                        }
                        break;

                }

                return false;
            }


        });
```

Every time i swipe these items sometimes it shows 1 and sometimes 5 meaning it is not behaving properly. Can someone please help me get through this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Updating the textView in `onTouchEvent()`'s  `case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`